# Unquote elements from a vector of variable names R

Tags: r

I have a vector with some dataframe names:

```
myvector<-c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Now, in a for loop, I would like to do some manipulation to each dataframe named with 'myvector' elements, so I would like to unquote its elements.

```
myvector2<-c(a, b, c, d)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `get` to get a single dataframe in a loop.

```
for (vec in myvector) {
     df <- get(vec)
     #Do some stuff
}
```

Or use `mget` to get list of dataframes and then apply some function with `lapply`.

```
lapply(mget(myvector), function(x) {
    #Do some stuff
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(mget(myvector), ~ f1(.x))
```